# git clone ssh identity file not accessible

Tags: ssh, git

I am using git.sh on [this](https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command/) link, and I have key file:

```
sh-3.2# ls -al /Users/tiina/.ssh/id_rsa/
drw-------  4 tiina  en   136 Jun 18 19:26 .
drwx------  5 tiina  en   170 Mar 15  2016 ..
-rw-------@ 1 tiina  en  1482 Jun 18 19:19 pri_rsa.ppk
```

but when I run on mac

```
./git.sh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa/pri_rsa.ppk clone ssh://tiina@scm.private.com:2222/foo
Cloning into 'portal'...
Warning: Identity file /Users/tiina/.ssh/id_rsa/pri_rsa.ppk not accessible: Permission denied.
Load key "/Users/tiina/.ssh/id_rsa": Is a directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

EDIT:
It turns out I made two mistakes here. when using ssh in mac, should convert private key from ppk to pem first:

```
puttygen xxx.ppk -O private-openssh -o xxx.pem
```

(install putty first using `sudo brew install putty`)

Comment: Your file `pri_rsa.ppk` has extended attributes.  Add the output of `ls -@l` to show them.  Also, is this a private key in a format usable by openssh on OSX, or is it (as the extension suggests) a PuTTY private key?

Comment: @user4556274 I think it is a putty private key. should I change it into a pem? after using Tamar's answer the accessible problem is gone, but still cannot git clone because "permission denied (pubickey)"

Comment: Yes. You should convert it to OpenSSH using PuTTYgen tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod u+x /Users/tiina/.ssh/id_rsa/
```